# How to display Distinct values Only in an Array, Java Programming

Tags: java, arrays

This is my post first here and I wanted to know how to remove elements in an array that have already been entered. for an assignment due Monday. The console will print all values entered in a distinct manner meaning it will only print values that have only been entered once.

People will be prompted with the message "Enter an integer" ten times and the system will take those values and remove any duplicates but only displaying one of the two entered. I.E if 17 is entered twice only display the first 17.

So here's my code I have so far

```
    import java.util.Scanner;   
    import java.util.Arrays;



public class Unit03Prog2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  //Array
int Numbers[] = new int[10];


Scanner Numb = new Scanner(System.in);

for(int i=0; i < Numbers.length; i++){

System.out.print("Enter an integer: "); 

      //Stores it, and moves to the next line         
     Numbers[i]= Numb.nextInt();



//Removes duplicates

//Code to remove duplicates goes here VVVV




//Ends it if i = 10
if(i == Numbers.length)
{
        break;

    }





//End of for statement

}

System.out.println("The number of distinct values is  " + Arrays.toString(Numbers)); 



//end of main method

}


//end of Class

}
```

So the code works and all but it displays every value entered no matter what. I only need numbers that have only been entered once

I.E

```
Enter an integer : 11
Enter an integer : 12
Enter an integer : 13
Enter an integer : 14
Enter an integer : 15
Enter an integer : 16
Enter an integer : 16
Enter an integer : 17
Enter an integer : 19
Enter an integer : 19
```

It should say The number of distinct values is 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 19

Thanks guys,
Joshua.

Comment: `if(i == Numbers.length) {  break; }`: at the end of the loop is **entirely unnecessary**; your 'for' loop _already does that_.

Comment: yeah I realized that today, already removed it. lol thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Set` to solve it:

```
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Set;


    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            //Array
            int Numbers[] = new int[10];
            Set<Integer> integerSet = new HashSet<>();
            Scanner Numb = new Scanner(System.in);
            for(int i=0; i < Numbers.length; i++){
                System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
                //Stores it, and moves to the next line
                Numbers[i]= Numb.nextInt();

                //Removes duplicates
                //Code to remove duplicates goes here VVVV
                integerSet.add(new Integer(Numbers[i]));

                if(i == Numbers.length) {
                    break;
                }

            }
            System.out.println("The number of distinct values is  " + Arrays.toString(integerSet.toArray()));

        }

    }
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much! I was stressing out like crazy about it.  Thank you for all the replies I didn't think I would get answers that quick!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Use a Set, which only contains unique element, to achieve your purpose.

Maybe you need to keep the sequence of input, but Set does not keep sequence.
I think you want to have a logic to remove duplicated records in an  array, right?
Try this:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Set;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Array
        int Numbers[] = new int[10];         
        Set<Integer> integerSet = new HashSet<>();
        Scanner Numb = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=0; i < Numbers.length; i++){
            System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
            //Stores it, and moves to the next line
            Numbers[i]= Numb.nextInt();           
            integerSet.add(new Integer(Numbers[i]));             
        }
        //Array to keep unique items with same sequence of input
        int uniqueNumbers[] =  new int[integerSet.size()];
        integerSet= new HashSet<>();
        for(int i=0;i<Numbers.length;i++){
            if(!integerSet.contains(Numbers[i])){
                uniqueNumbers[integerSet.size()]=Numbers[i];
                integerSet.add(Numbers[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The number of distinct values is  " + Arrays.toString(uniqueNumbers));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the code to remove the duplicates. I suggest to before inserting into the array, check for duplicates. If the entered number is duplicate, skip it and read the next input.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Unit03Prog2 { 
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       //Array 
       int Numbers[] = new int[10];
       Scanner Numb = new Scanner(System.in);
       int j = 0;
       int inputNumber;
       boolean isDuplicate;

       for(int i=0; i < Numbers.length; i++){ 
           isDuplicate = false;
           System.out.print("Enter an integer: "); 

           //Stores it, and moves to the next line 
           inputNumber = Numb.nextInt(); 

          //Removes duplicates 
         //Code to remove duplicates goes here VVVV //Ends it if i = 10 
         for (int k=0; k<j; k++) {
             if(inputNumber == Numbers [k]) {
                 isDuplicate = true;
                 break;
              }
          }

          if(! isDuplicate) {
                Numbers[j++] = inputNumber;
           }
      //End of for statement 
      } 

      System.out.println("The number of distinct values is " + Arrays.toString(Numbers)); 
  //end of main method 
  } 
//end of Class
}
```

Comment: Yeah thanks all of you all of you gave great responses! Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,1,2};
    
    for(int i=0; i<a.length;i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for(int j=0; j<a.length;j++) {
            if(a[i]==a[j] && i!=j) {
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
            if(count == 0) {
                System.out.println(a[i]);
                
            }
    }
}
```